# TypeError: state.categoriesState.push is not a function VUEX

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have this error but I do not understand the reason, could you guide me?

Error:

> TypeError: state.categoriesState.push is not a function

My code:

**state.js**

```
export default {
    categoriesState: []
}
```

**mutations.js**

```
export function setCategories(state, category){
    state.categoriesState.push(category);    
};
```

**Calling **VUEX** from my component:**

```
methods: {
...mapMutations('cat', ['setCategories']),

        addCategoriesToVuex(category){
            this.setCategories(category);
        },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your variable **categoriesState** is an **object** and not an array. You should check that first by doing console of typeOf of your variable **categoriesState**.

```
export function setCategories(state, category){
      console.log(typeOf(state.categoriesState));
    //state.categoriesState.push(category);    
};
```

You can use set method to add new property to an object in vue.

Comment: It is an array but I do not know why it was treated as an object, I just changed the name to that state of vuex and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Me too did the same what you did and it worked @OscarDev

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it was because of vuex-persistedstate package. As @OscarDev mentioned, change of variable name helped. It is because persistedstate saved the type of variable when you were writing the code.
So clearing the persistedstate cache helped too.